# why in results i am getting all friends instead of only 10friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

i am using this query

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in ('.implode(", ", $man).')';
```

to get uid, pic_squre, and sex of 10friends which are selected by user
and their user id is stored in $man[ ] an array

but when i see the results it is selecting all the friends of a user not the friends
only selected by a user
whats wrong?

This is what i am getting for all friends

```
 [12] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 100003033556875
                [sex] => female
                [pic_square] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/274747_1000

03033556875_306033850_q.jpg
    )
```

Comment: these are the values in $man 
100002131686032, 1602023867, 100000297352382, 100000501703505, 1257699872, 100003033556875, 100002474721536, 1075440919, 100001676304188, 100000925253290

Comment: I just tried your query and it works fine: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20sex%2C%20pic_square%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20in%20(100002131686032%2C%201602023867%2C%20100000297352382%2C%20100000501703505%2C%201257699872%2C%20100003033556875%2C%20100002474721536%2C%201075440919%2C%20100001676304188%2C%20100000925253290)%3B

Answer (score -1):

You should add LIMIT clause

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid, sex, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in ('.implode(", ", $man).') LIMIT 10';
```

Comment: Adding the `LIMIT` clause will get 10, but from my understanding, the OP is adding 10 Facebook users to the array, so it should only be returning 10 records.

Comment: tried LIMIT its still giving me all the results and why i am getting all results when in $man array there is only 10values with friends id?

Comment: @NeilKnight yes thats what i am saying it is returning me all the results?